# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

Tags: php

I have this warning but I have not found what causes this error, please guys can you light me?
The error is in line 58 ---> $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) or die();{
I searched for a while but can't find how i tacle that error called.

"Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:.... on line 58"

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');

$user_id = 0;

function print_header($title="Header") { ?>

<title>PDS</title>


<html>
<body>

<?php 


global $user_id;
if (logged_in()){
    $session_user_id = $_COOKIE['pds-usn'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'id', 'name', 'hashed_pw', 'email', 'last_name', 'email', 'site', 'level', 'joined', 'posts', 'type');
    echo $user_data['name'];
    echo 'U bent ingelogd als '.$_COOKIE['pds-usn'].'. <a href="login.php?logout=1">Uitloggen</a>';
}   else {
    echo "U bent niet ingelogd. <a href='login.php'>Login</a> of <a href='register.php'>registreer</a>.";
}



?>


<?php }


function print_footer() { ?>

</body>
</html>

<?php }

function user_data($user_id) {

include('connect.php');

$data = array();
$user_id = (int)$user_id;

$func_num_args = func_num_args();
$func_get_args = func_get_args();

if ($func_num_args > 0) {
    unset($func_get_args[0]);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
    $sql = "SELECT $fields FROM users WHERE id = $user_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) or die();
    return $data;

}   
}else {
    return false;
}

?>
```

Connect.php:

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(header('Location: errorpage.php?error=2'));
mysqli_select_db($connect, "pds_news_feed") or die(header('Location: errorpage.php?error=3'));
?>
```

Comment: Please post the "connect.php" file.

Comment: @JesseSchokker I editted the post

Comment: Please note that your code is vulnerable for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for alert but i know :). This page isn't for public use it's just to practice forums etc.

Comment: Usually this happens when the query  give a false (boolean) instead of a result.

Comment: @GiacomoPittalis Yeah but i checked for a typo like 100 times

Comment: Try to echo the query and test it direct in phpmyadmin or whatever you use to manage db

Comment: Than i get this:

SELECT `id`, `name`, `hashed_pw`, `email`, `last_name`, `email`, `site`, `level`, `joined`, `posts`, `type` FROM users WHERE id = 0

Wich is oke? Expect the id = 0. I guess it has to be id = 1?

Comment: yes, it seems that the query is incorrect. That id=0 is quite odd

Comment: Do you maybe see the fault in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php) returns `FALSE` on error. If you pass this return value to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` without checking it first, you get the warning/error you describe. You should therefore check the return value of `mysqli_query()`, and if it is `FALSE`, you can get the error from [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php), e.g.:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
if ($result === FALSE) {
  die(mysqli_error($connect));
}
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
return $data;
```

Comment: Thanks i found the detailed error and i changed the query and now it's worked :)